# namenode datanode jps is not listing in windows command?

Tags: hadoop, hdfs

after starting the hdfs namenode -format command
it wont list the namenode and datanode in jps command

I still didn't try anything because all the answers in Linux command and I want for windows command

Answer (score 0):

That is the windows command

Format only does what it says, and doesn't do anything for the datanode(s). You still need to **start** the namenode and datanode, such as with `start-dfs` or `hdfs namenode start` and `hdfs datanode start`

Both with print errors if they're unable to start (causing them not to show up with jps)